# Java Mail API send mail with another mail attached

Tags: java, email, attachment, send

I want to ask how can I send a message with Java Mail API with attachment another mail.

```
MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart ( );
attachmentPart.setContent ( mail , "text/?" );
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: not able to understand your problem ...

Comment: I just want to attach a mail to another one. My question is how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javax.mail.Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart =   new  javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart();

multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

javax.activation.DataSource source = new FileDataSource("C:\\Notes\\new mail.msg");

messageBodyPart.setDataHandler( new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName("new mail.msg");

multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
msg.setContent(multipart);

 MimeBodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
 part.setText(text);

multipart.addBodyPart(part);
```

Comment: Everything is fine but there is one problem. When I send the email with another email attached to it the Microsoft Outlook don't want to open the attached mail.

Comment: I've found that is a different encoding.

Comment: @JordanBorisov In this case attached email need to be saved. Right ? I am working on a requirement in which i have to create a mail and without sending it i have to attach it in another mail. I am not sure if it's possible. Can you please help ?